# Add numbers to existing listview row C#

Tags: c#, listview

I want to add number to each row in listview.

Right now i count how many files i have in a folder , add that number to string array. Then with for loop i add a number in to this array and add elements in to
listview.

But number is being added only to the first row. [image]

Code :

```
int countFile = Directory.GetFiles(saveAnimePath + "\\Watching", "*.txt").Length;

                string[] filesCount = new string[countFile];

                int number = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < filesCount.Length; i++)
                {
                    number = number + 1;
                    filesCount[i] = number.ToString();
                }

                foreach (var item in filesCount)
                {
                    lvWatching.Items[0].Text = item;
                }
```

How to add number to each row ?

Comment: how are you bind your listview ?

Comment: is this in winform application ? where is the list view code ?

Comment: @JitendraAanadi yes it is winform. Ssry for not mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the row of the item for each interaction in: `lvWatching.Items[0].Text = item;`

For example:

```
    int countFile = Directory.GetFiles(saveAnimePath + "\\Watching", "*.txt").Length;

    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filesCount.Length; i++)
    {
      number = number + 1;
      lvWatching.Items[i].Text = number.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the last foreach statement you edit only first item in ListView.

Instead of foreach, try using for, something like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i++; i < filesCount)
{
    lvWatching.Items[i].Text = filesCount[i];
}
```

**Edit**

But I think your method is much overhead.
Assuming that in the list you are displaying all files from the directory, there is no need to Get them again, get their count, assign numbers and so on.
You could just iterate through the list items and assign the correct number.

The whole "assigning numbers operation" would look something like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i++; i < lvWatching.Items.Length)
{
    lvWatching.Items[i].Text = i.ToString();
}
```

But I might missing something so it could not work in every situation.